# app/components/rocket/rocket-search.ts(63,10): error TS2339: Property 'intercomSettings' does not exist on type 'Window'

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, intercom

- I am trying to use intercom in my app.
- its working fine when I put inside script tag  in index.html
- but when I try to use in .ts file I am getting below error.
  **app/components/rocket/rocket-search.ts(63,10): error TS2339: Property 'intercomSettings' does not exist on type 'Window'.**
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code below

**not working code**

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Input, Output, EventEmitter, Inject, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { KendoGridComponent } from '../grid/grid.component'
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { sportsService } from '../../services/sports.service';


@Component({
    selector: 'rocketSearch',
    templateUrl: "./app/components/rocket/rocket-search.html",
})

export class rocketSearch {
    /* Localization variables */

    @Output() rocketSearchEmitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

    private dataSourceVal;
    private MainGrid;
    private grid;
    private titles;
    public rocketRef;

    constructor( public elementRef: ElementRef, public router: Router, public sportsService: sportsService) {
    }
    private kendocommand = {
        edit: { createAt: "bottom" },
        autoBind: false,
        excelFileName: {
            fileName: "",
            allPages: true
        }
    }

    ngOnInit() {

        let that = this;
        let attributes = this.sportsService.getSeesionStorageValue();
        // if (attributes) {
        //  this.userId = attributes.user_attributes.SSO[0];
        // }

        //app/components/rocket/rocket-search.ts(63,10): error TS2339: Property 'intercomSettings' does not exist on type 'Window'.


        window.intercomSettings = {
            app_id: 'irgooiqb',
            name: "Jane Doe", // Full name
            email: "customer@example.com", // Email address
            created_at: 1312182000 // Signup date as a Unix timestamp
        };
        //console.log(.log(this.userId);
    }

}
```

**working code inside index.html**

```
<script>
    (function(){var w=window;var ic=w.Intercom;if(typeof ic==="function"){ic('reattach_activator');ic('update',intercomSettings);}else{var d=document;var i=function(){i.c(arguments)};i.q=[];i.c=function(args){i.q.push(args)};w.Intercom=i;function l(){var s=d.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.async=true;s.src='https://widget.intercom.io/widget/APP_ID';var x=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];x.parentNode.insertBefore(s,x);}if(w.attachEvent){w.attachEvent('onload',l);}else{w.addEventListener('load',l,false);}}})()
</script>

<script>
    let players=this.sportsService.marksSession();
    console.log("players--->" + players);
    if(players) {
        this.userId = players.user_players.SSO[0];
    }

    Intercom('trackEvent', 'share-link');

    window.intercomSettings = {
        app_id: 'APP_ID',
        name: "Jane Doe", // Full name
        email: "customer@example.com", // Email address
        created_at: 1312182000 // Signup date as a Unix timestamp
    };
</script>
```

Comment: you need to declare a variable before you can use it. from where you are getting intercom settings?

Comment: @Prajwal hey thanks for your reply...intercomSettings is coming from js api...can you update in my code ..its confusing